# Some dlls go missing during deployment/publishing with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I'm working with VSTO Outlook Add-In build with Visual Studio 2010. I'm using the same version of Visual Studio on Windows 10.

In the references of the of the project there is `System.Net.Http`. However, when I publish the project, I can't see `System.Net.Http.dll.deploy` or anything like it. When I install the Add-In and run, I get the exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can someone help? How can I fix this? During debugging there's no issue. I don't get the same error. Only when I deploy to UAT I get this. Thanks.

Comment: what OS is the UAT machine?

Comment: I had this same issue, for me it was assembly bindings were messed up. Go to build options and turn build verbosity to detailed and check that log for any errors about assembly bindings.

Comment: OS is Windows 7 Enterprise N, 64-Bit. @Stuart Thanks, will check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try go into Project references and select System.Net.Http.dll and check properties if Copy Local is set to "True", if it is not then set it to True and rebuild your project.

Comment: Copy Local is set to true. I deleted the whole project and created a fresh clone from the repo. This fixed the issue.